# Set Instance Variables by Void Method instead of Getting Return Values

Tags: java, arrays, function, oop, netbeans

I have a default constructor `setStudent`:

```
public void setStudent (String sName, int sTest1, int sTest2, int sTest3, int sTest4, double sOverall, String sGrade) {
  name = sName;
  test1 = sTest1;
  test2 = sTest2;
  test3 = sTest3;
  test4 = sTest4;
  overallMarks = sOverall;
  grade = sGrade;
}
```

*as well as the requires `setters` and `getters` for each variable.

I get input of `test1` `test2` `test3` `test4` from user.

---

`overallMarks` is calculated via `calOverall`:

```
public double calOverall(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4) {

        double o = (((a1 / 100.0) * 20) + ((a2 / 100.0) * 20) + ((p / 100.0) * 10) + ((e / 100.0) * 50));

        return o;
    }
```

---

`grade` is calculated base on `overallMarks` via `calGrade` :

```
public String calGrade(double overallMarks) {

        if (overallMarks >= 85) {
            return "A";
        } else if (o >= 70) {
            return "B";
        } else if (o >= 60) {
            return "C";
        } else if (o >= 50) {
            return "D";
        } else {
            return "F";
        }
    }
```

---

My `main` method that creates the student object after getting all input:

*currently using all functions that returns value

```
overall = studentList[studentIndex].calOverall(test1, test2, test3, test4);

grade= studentList[studentIndex].calGrade(overall);

studentList[studentIndex].setStudent(name, test1, test2, test3, test4, overall, grade);
```

However, I realized that my project requires me to calculate overall mark and grade by void methods that set the appropriate instance variables.

---

May I know how can I set my calculation of `overall` and `grade` as void methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps instead of returning a value, you just saved it on your `overallMarks` variable.

`calOverall` is a void method to calculate overall and save

```
public void calOverall(int t1, int t2, int t3, int t4) {
    overallMarks = (((a1 / 100.0) * 20) + ((a2 / 100.0) * 20) + ((p / 100.0) * 10) + ((e / 100.0) * 50));
}
```

Then use your getter method to use that value

```
public double getOverallMarks() {
    return overallMarks;
}
```

In your `main` method you call

```
studentList[studentIndex].calOverall(test1, test2, test3, test4);
```

Then get the value:

```
double overall = studentList[studentIndex].getOverallMarks();
```